# Вызывается деструктор при выходе из метода

Tags: c++, деструктор

Почему на 29 строке вызывается деструктор Object и данные в массиве теряются? Я совсем ничего не понимаю.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
 
using namespace std;
 
class MyArray {
protected:
    double* array;
    int size;
public:
    MyArray(double *array, int size);
    ~MyArray();
    void FirstMethod(MyArray Object);
    void SecondMethod(MyArray Object);
};
MyArray::MyArray(double *iarray, int isize) {
    size = isize;
    array = new double[size];
    for (int _ = 0; _ < size; _++) {
        array[_] = iarray[_];
    }
}
MyArray::~MyArray() {
    cout << "delete\n";
    delete[] array;
}
void MyArray::FirstMethod(MyArray Object) {}
void MyArray::SecondMethod(MyArray Object) {
    FirstMethod(Object);
    cout << endl;
}
int main() {
    double firstArray[3] = {31, 32, 33};
    MyArray firstObject(firstArray, 3);
    double secondArray[3] = {7.8, 8.3, 7.6};
    MyArray secondObject(secondArray, 3);
    firstObject.SecondMethod(secondObject);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В вашем классе не хватает правильно определенного копирующего конструктора. Из-за этого внутренний массив используется больше чем одним экземпляром класса. Копирование объекта происходит, в часности, при вызове функции. При этом создается временный объект - аргумент, который при выходе из функции удаляется и для него вызывается деструктор.

Comment: У вас еще и UB с вероятным крашем... Вы же объект копируете при передаче в функцию? Копируете... А сгенерированный компилятором копирующий конструктор выполняет поверхностное копирование. Так что один и тот же указатель вы в деструкторе будете освобождать дважды. Нет уж, написали свой конструктор и деструктор - будьте любезны написать и копирующий конструктор, и оператор присваивания!

Comment: `Object`, как и другие аргументы функции, является переменной с автоматическим временем хранения разрушаются после ее возврата. Видимо кто-то не в курсе про возможность передачи по ссылке.

Answer (score -3):

Ну а чего Вы хотите? Метод получает параметр по значению, а по значению можно получить только копию параметра, эта копия при завершении метода и удаляется. Это нормально.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/825776)

Comment: Ну не смешно же.